# Kafka - Consumer Full Data Refresh

Tags: java, apache-kafka

For many reasons the consumer need to perform a full data refresh, it could be due to data failure or a new consumer is on boarding.

I was wondering how can the consumer perform a full data refresh when the initial offset which contains full data gets removed after the retention period? Subsequent offset 2, 3, 4, and so on are only having delta changes. Without the first offset the data will not be complete.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. It cannot. You would need to increase retention time to avoid that this data get's deleted in the first place.

However, if you have "delta updates" it might be better not to store those into Kafka, but to apply those updates to the date and store a new version, ie, instead of A, delta-1-A, delta-2-A you store A1, A2, A3, (with A1 = A, A2 = A + delta-1-A, etc). Furthermore, you can change the topics `cleanup.policy` from "retention" to "compaction" -- this ensures that Kafka never deletes the latest version of you data (per key).

Comment: Thanks Matthias. Each A1, A2, A3 contains the full set of data, consumer loading performance might be impacted if we have huge data volume, isn't it  ?

Comment: Don't know what your data type is. Let's say it's a count, you can store 1, 3, 2 (as delta) or 1, 4, 6 (as current count) -- data size is the same here. Furthermore, on load, in the first case you read 3 records, while in the later case (after topic got compacted) you read only a single value, ie, 6. So it depends (as so ofter :)). And even if data size increase and has performance impact, it is your call to make the decision between correctness and performance...